# What is the name of the graph where any edge is part of a cycle?

Tags: graphs, terminology

I wonder if there is a special category for this kind of graphs, I am thinking of a bidirectional graph but it would also be interesting in the cases when it is undirected.

I am thinking of something like **recursively cyclic** maby.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Such a graph is called *bridgeless*.